# Glassfish 3 Cant update JDK no way

Tags: glassfish-3

I was using 1.6.0_19 jdk and installed 1.6.0_20 jdk..
Glassfish doesn't like that...
Here are my windows environment variables..

```
 ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\
APPDATA=C:\Users\Parhs\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=PARHS-PC
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Parhs
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Parhs\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\PARHS-PC
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wb
em;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Toshiba\Bluetoot
h Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\apa
che-ant-1.8.1\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PHPRC=C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 14 Stepping 8, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0e08
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\Parhs\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Parhs\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=Parhs-PC
USERNAME=Parhs
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Parhs
VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
```

Also here is my asenv.bat

> REM DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT
>   NOTICES OR THIS HEADER. REM  REM
>   Copyright 2004-2009 Sun Microsystems,
>   Inc. All rights reserved. REM  REM Use
>   is subject to License Terms REM
>
> set AS_IMQ_LIB=....\mq\lib set
>   AS_IMQ_BIN=....\mq\bin set
>   AS_CONFIG=..\config set AS_INSTALL=..
>   set AS_DEF_DOMAINS_PATH=..\domains set
>   AS_DERBY_INSTALL=....\javadb set
>   AS_JAVA="C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"

And although restarting system and server i am getting this report

```
Operating System Information:
Name of the Operating System: Windows 7
Binary Architecture name of the Operating System: x86, Version: 6.1
Number of processors available on the Operating System: 2
System load on the available processors for the last minute: -1.0. (Sum of running and queued runnable entities per minute)

General Java Runtime Environment Information for the VM: 6152@Parhs-PC
JRE BootClassPath: C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\javax.annotation.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\jaxb-api-osgi.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\classes;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\lib\monitor\btrace-boot.jar
JRE ClassPath: C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\glassfish.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\lib\monitor\btrace-agent.jar
JRE Native Library Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin
JRE name: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. Version: 16.2-b04
List of System Properties for the Java Virtual Machine:
ANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING = true
AS_CONFIG = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..\config
AS_DEF_DOMAINS_PATH = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..\domains
AS_DERBY_INSTALL = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..\..\javadb
AS_IMQ_BIN = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..\..\mq\bin
AS_IMQ_LIB = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..\..\mq\lib
AS_INSTALL = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config\..
AS_JAVA = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
GlassFish_Platform = Felix
awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
catalina.base = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1
catalina.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1
catalina.useNaming = false
com.sun.aas.configRoot = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\config
com.sun.aas.derbyRoot = C:\glassfishv3\javadb
com.sun.aas.domainsRoot = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains
com.sun.aas.hostName = Parhs-PC
com.sun.aas.imqBin = C:\glassfishv3\mq\bin
com.sun.aas.imqLib = C:\glassfishv3\mq\lib
com.sun.aas.installRoot = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish
com.sun.aas.installRootURI = file:/C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/
com.sun.aas.instanceName = server
com.sun.aas.instanceRoot = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1
com.sun.aas.instanceRootURI = file:/C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/
com.sun.aas.javaRoot = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre
com.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class = com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
com.sun.enterprise.hk2.cacheDir = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
com.sun.enterprise.jaccprovider.property.repository = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/generated/policy
com.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias = s1as
common.loader = ${catalina.home}/common/classes,${catalina.home}/common/endorsed/*.jar,${catalina.home}/common/lib/*.jar
eclipselink.security.usedoprivileged = true
ejb.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\ejb
felix.config.properties = file:/C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/osgi/felix/conf/config.properties
felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true
felix.fileinstall.debug = 1
felix.fileinstall.dir = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/autostart/
felix.fileinstall.poll = 5000
felix.system.properties = file:/C:/glassfishv3/glassfish/osgi/felix/conf/system.properties
file.encoding = Cp1253
file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
file.separator = \
glassfish.version = GlassFish v3 (build 74.2)
hk2.startup.context.args = #Mon Jun 07 20:27:37 EEST 2010
-startup-classpath=C\:\\glassfishv3\\glassfish\\modules\\glassfish.jar;C\:\\glassfishv3\\glassfish\\lib\\monitor\\btrace-agent.jar
__time_zero=1275931657334
hk2.startup.context.mainModule=org.glassfish.core.kernel
-startup-args=--domain,,,domain1,,,--domaindir,,,C\:\\glassfishv3\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1
--domain=domain1
-startup-classname=com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
--domaindir=C\:\\glassfishv3\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1

hk2.startup.context.root = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules
http.nonProxyHosts = localhost|127.0.0.1|Parhs-PC
java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\glassfish.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\lib\monitor\btrace-agent.jar
java.class.version = 50.0
java.endorsed.dirs = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre/jre/lib/ext;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre
java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\Parhs\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin
java.net.useSystemProxies = true
java.rmi.server.randomIDs = true
java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_19-b04
java.security.auth.login.config = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
java.security.policy = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version = 1.6
java.util.logging.config.file = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\logging.properties
java.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vendor.url = http://java.sun.com/
java.vendor.url.bug = http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi
java.version = 1.6.0_19
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version = 1.0
java.vm.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.version = 16.2-b04
javax.net.ssl.keyStore = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword = changeit
javax.net.ssl.trustStore = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword = changeit
javax.rmi.CORBA.PortableRemoteObjectClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject
javax.rmi.CORBA.StubClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.StubDelegateImpl
javax.rmi.CORBA.UtilClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util
javax.security.jacc.PolicyConfigurationFactory.provider = com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl
jdbc.drivers = org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
jpa.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\jpa
line.separator = 

org.glassfish.web.rfc2109_cookie_names_enforced = false
org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.autostartBundles = osgi-adapter.jar, org.apache.felix.shell.jar, org.apache.felix.shell.remote.jar, org.apache.felix.configadmin.jar, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.jar
org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.bundlesDir = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules
org.jvnet.hk2.osgimain.excludedSubDirs = autostart/
org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl
org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton
org.osgi.framework.storage = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
os.arch = x86
os.name = Windows 7
os.version = 6.1
osgi.shell.telnet.ip = 127.0.0.1
osgi.shell.telnet.maxconn = 1
osgi.shell.telnet.port = 6666
package.access = 
package.definition = 
path.separator = ;
security.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\security
server.loader = ${catalina.home}/server/classes,${catalina.home}/server/lib/*.jar
shared.loader = ${catalina.home}/shared/classes,${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar
sun.arch.data.model = 32
sun.boot.class.path = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\javax.annotation.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\jaxb-api-osgi.jar;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\classes;C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\lib\monitor\btrace-boot.jar
sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian = little
sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
sun.desktop = windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1253
sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler
sun.os.patch.level = 
user.country = GR
user.dir = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1
user.home = C:\Users\Parhs
user.language = el
user.name = Parhs
user.timezone = Europe/Athens
user.variant = 
web.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\web
weld.home = C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\modules\weld
```

Why is it so hard??? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Glassfish v3 with Java 1.6.0_20, I didn't change anything in `asenv.bat` and I don't have any problem. However, I have the `java` executable in the `PATH` (i.e.  `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in the `PATH`). You don't (and I would fix this, I would not touch the `asenv.bat`, and try again).

Comment: The VM used to run the launcher tools and the VM configured to run  glassfish need to be the same (for some reason).  I have experienced the same problem on solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it saves someone some PITA, I had receive the same error, having had defined the JAVA_HOME with quotes. Mine JAVA_HOME was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\" and in the PATH %JAVA_HOME%\bin was present. The java, eclipse, tomcat ant and quite a few other java programmes would start, but the glassfish would not.